# How to use またしても?

Tags: word-choice, usage, jlpt, word-usage

I know that またしても means "again, moreover, in addition" and it often comes with relative nuance. However, given the below sentences, I don't know why it's only proper in a sentence but not both.

> 1/ **またしても**、政治家の金に関する問題が明らかになった。
>
> 2/ 強すぎる冷暖房は体に良くないし、**またしても**、環境にも悪い。

The correct answer is 1.

Comment: ［副］繰り返されるさま。またまた。またもや。「―優勝を逸してしまった」--　ディジタル大辞泉

Comment: My dictionary says it means 'again' in the sense of "once more". It does not mention the 'moreover' meaning. This would exclude option 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1) 「**またしても**、[政治家]{せいじか}の[金]{かね}に[関]{かん}する[問題]{もんだい}が[明]{あき}らかになった。」
>
> 2) 「[強]{つよ}すぎる[冷暖房]{れいだんぼう}は[体]{からだ}に[良]{よ}くないし、**またしても**、[環境]{かんきょう}にも[悪]{わる}い。」

「またしても」 is an emphatic way of saying 「また」("again").  To use it correctly, you must have a situation where the same or a similar event has occured ***once again***.  In addition, 「またしても」 is usually, if not always, used when something undesirable has happened again.

Sentence #1 is perfect as it is about the reccurance of a money scandal by a politician - an undesirable event happening once again.  It is just 100% correct and natural.

Sentence #2 makes little sense.  Why?  Because first of all, nothing is happening once again in the sentence, is it?  It is "trying" to say that excessive use of air-conditioning is bad for your body as well as for the environment.  It is using 「またしても」 to mean something like "in addition to that" or "moreover" when it just does not have those meanings.

In Sentence #2, 「またしても」 should be replaced by a simple 「また」 to make sense.  In that case, 「また」 means "moreover" and ***not*** "again".

Answer (score 4):

[またしても](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/thsrs/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82/m0u/) and the related [またまた](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F) can be translated as "once again" which makes these two examples clear on the usage.

> 1/ またしても、政治家の金に関する問題が明らかになった。

Once again, problems involving politician's money has come to light. <-- correct

> 2/ 強すぎる冷暖房は体に良くないし、またしても、環境にも悪い。

Not only is over-powered air conditioning not good for your body, once again (??), it is also bad for the environment. <-- not correct

I think the question is trying to get at the nuance difference between またしても/またまた(once again) and just [また](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F) ('moreover' or 'also').